# Moving table using SQLAlchemy from one DB to another

Tags: sqlalchemy

How can I move a table that I have read from a database using SQLAlchemy to another database ???
Should I use SQLAlchemy or i can use psycopg2 either way how will I be able to do it?
The code is as follows :

```py
engine = db.create_engine('mysql://dwhuser:xyz@abc:123/database')
connection = engine.connect()

sec_engine = db.create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/test_landing')
sec_connection = sec_engine.connect()

src_table = db.Table('src_table', metadata, autoload_with=engine)
dest_table_land = db.Table('dest_table', metadata, autoload_with=sec_engine)


query = db.select(src_table)
Result = connection.execute(query)
```

How an I send this `src_table` to another DB , such as postgres or mysql ??

Comment: You mention `psycopg2`, a lib for `postgresql` but both database URI strings are for `mysql`?  What database are you using?  Both `postgresql` and `mysql` have tools for importing and export data if the schemas are the same and it is from the same db server to the same db server (ie. postgresql to postgresql OR mysql to mylsq).  Maybe you can provide more specific information.

Comment: For example export and importing across different database servers is much more difficult, ie. `mysql` INTO `postgresql` OR `postgresql` INTO `mysql`.  Are you trying to do that too ?